# Django Model field reference ForeignKey.to_field not working

Tags: django, django-models, foreign-keys, django-2.0

I'm trying to create a `order` model that is referencing the non primary-key field `rfid` of my user model. In order to do that I'm using a foreign-key relationship using the attribute `to_field`.

My user model is inheriting from `AbstractUser` and I added the `rfid` field with `unique=True` that is necessary for the `to_field` attribute:

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    rfid = models.IntegerField(unique=True, null=True, blank=True)
```

Following the order model:

```
class Order(models.Model):
    rfid = models.ForeignKey('CustomUser', on_delete=models.CASCADE, to_field="rfid")
    coffee = models.ForeignKey('Coffee', on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    amount = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    datetime = models.DateTimeField()
```

Having a look in the django-admin there still are the usernames listed for the `rfid` reference instead of the actual `rfid` entries that are made in the database. I attatched a [picture on Imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9KEvo.jpg) as I haven't got he reputation yet to post images on here.

Why is that? I studied other posts but couldn't figure it out.

Comment: Your picture doesn't show anything at all relevant to `to_field`. It just shows the default string representation of the linked models. Are you actually sure you understand what `to_field` does, and that you need to set to_field at all?

Comment: To my understanding the to_field attribute allows to reference a different field than the default primary-key field referenced by django.
The picture clearly shows that the field 'rfid' still contains the username attribute instead of the referenced rfid field (to_field="rfid").
If I understand it wrong please enlighten me or maybe there is a different method how I can reference the rfid field to my order model.

Comment: No, the picture shows the *representation* of the linked model, which is determined by its `__str__` method. You can change that by overriding the form class and redefining the relevant field, if you want to. There is rarely any reason to change the to_field, as the fk itself gives you access to the whole linked model.